# DIV / Form alignment

Tags: css, forms, html

First let me start off by saying that I am NO web developer. I work more on embedded stuff. I am completely ignorant to the web design standards or common practices. Any help with be much appreciated.

**What I am trying to accomplish**

To make a form with several rows of checkboxes / drop downs / textboxes that is incredibly simple and intuitive to operate. It has to be compatible fully with IE 6+. Any other browsers are non mandatory (this is an in house solution that will only be viewed on IE).

The thing I have been trying to accomplish is create another column of checkboxes that align like the current set.

Here is what it currently looks like in IE

**My code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<style type="text/css">
.right_div_check_boxes { width:70%;float:right;} <!-- 75% -->
.left_div_input_boxes {width:15%;float:left;}    <!--15%-->

</style>




<div class="left_div_input_boxes" style="position:relative">

    <form>
    <label>Submitted by (First Name)</label>
    <input type="text" style="width:150px" name="firstname" /><br>
    <label>Submitted by (Last Name)</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname"/>
    <label>Employee Number</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="employnum"/>


    <form>
    <label>What</label>
    <select style="width:150px" name="observer">
    <option value="other">TEST</option>
    <option value="other">TEST</option>
    <option value="other">TEST</option>
    </select>


    <label>Who</label>
    <form action="">
    <select style="width:150px" name="who">
    <option value="other">TEST</option>
    <option value="other">TEST</option>
    <option value="other">TEST</option>
    </select>




    <label>Operation Code</label>
    <select  style="width:150px"  name="opcode">
                       <option value="other">TEST</option>
                       <option value="other">TEST</option>
                    </select>



                    <label>Center</label>
                    <select style="width:150px" name="cost">

                        <option value="Zone 1"> Zone 1 </option>
                        <option value="Zone 2"> Zone 2 </option>
                        <option value="Zone 3"> Zone 3 </option>
                    </select>
                    </form>

</div>


<div class="right_div_check_boxes" style="position:relative">
<label>Dangers</label>
<form>

<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" />Line of Fire<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" />Respirtory Protection<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" />Ears/Hearing Protection<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" />Eye/Face Protection<br />
</div>
<br />



</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can we have a link to an example page, or a screenshot of what you have/what you want to achieve?

Comment: Why do you declare style="position:relative" in-line rather than in the css with the rest of the style?

Answer (score 0):

Use a table instead of a div. If you need to add more rows, that is at least as simple as adding more rows in this context. Adding another column of checkboxes is also just as easy. Simply add another column to the table.

Answer (score 0):

Heres what you want to do. Wrap the left column form in a div with this class:

```
.left_column {
float:left;
width:50%;

}
```

And the right column with a div with this class:

```
 .right_column {
    float:right;
    width:50%;

    }
```